# When does OneDrive for Business change file contents?

Tags: document-library, onedrive-for-business

According to a recent article, one user found that his [file contents were changed after sync](http://www.myce.com/news/microsoft-onedrive-for-business-modifies-files-as-it-syncs-71168/). I repeated the expiriment with an HTML file and found it unchanged. However, I don't doubt that in some circumstances this could happen. I've seen lots of changes to files uploaded to SharePoint, generally related to SharePoint Designer.

The question is, why would this happen? If we don't know the cause, I wonder if there are repeatable cases of this or if there are flaws in the article author's methods.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing OD4B to Box is not apples-to-apples.

If i have columns in the library, and those columns have default values, then I expect the updated metadata to be in the files once they are added to SharePoint.

Just more haters being haters.

=================================================

The observed behavior is called Property demotion and is well documented in the 2010 docs: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543341(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543341%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, both Box and Microsoft are promoting the comparison. Is it wrong to expect if SharePoint changes the contents of your document the modified date and modified by metadata stay in sync?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenXML (i.e. docx files) Sharepoint adds metadata to the document.

Comment: Please provide more details.